# If column "a" in sheet1 matches column "a" in sheet2 then replace entire row in sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare column A in sheet1 to column A in sheet2.

If the values match, copy data from sheet2 into sheet1 into the row that matches values.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I have only been able to write a code to replace specific cell/column, but this completely didn't work as the columns in sheet2 (the sheet from which I would like to copy data) are in different order than in sheet1 (the sheet to which I wanted to copy data from sheet2).

Comment: The order shouldn't matter since you can refer to a worksheet by name as well as by index. (depending on your code)

Comment: In the question you say "if value from column A (sheet1) matches the value in column B (sheet2)" but the title only mentions column A. So if they match you want to copy columns B,C,D,G to B,C,D,E

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, indeed. If data in column A (sheet1) matches data in column A (sheet2) I wanted to copy entire row (but only for matching headers if that makes any sense?).

For example, sheet2 has more columns than sheet1, so I want to skip these "extra" columns as these are not needed.
The hole sheet is around 1,5k rows and I have been doing changes manualy so far....

Comment: Why use macros here? Couldn’t you just create a formula in a new sheet 3? It looks like you just want to “overwrite” data in sheet one, so basic formulas (“=“, “<>”, “vlookup”, “hlookup”) could do the trick. Simply paste values when done.

Comment: Have you shown a simplified versions of your real data which has a lot more columns to match ? Do you want the macro to find the matching columns rather than "hard code" them and how many columns do you have roughly ?

Comment: @CDP1802 sheet1 is around 1k~rows and A-Z columns, sheet2 is around 1,5k rows and A-AX columns (so it's more date in sheet2 than in sheet1), sheet2 is generated by system and based on sheet2 I need to update data in sheet1 (I can't do any changes to sheet1 like sorting etc) I can only replace data "as it is".
I am working for a bank, so I can't really copy anything from my work laptop so I have made a simply example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Dictionary Object to match header names on sheet2 with those on sheet1.

update - added trim to convert numbers to strings

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

    Const ROW_HEADER = 1

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arID, id As String, n As Long, m As Variant
    
    Dim dictCol As Object, k As String
    Set dictCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   ' profile sheet2 columns
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws2
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arID = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value2 ' range of iDs
        
        lastcol = .Cells(ROW_HEADER, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For c = 1 To lastcol
            k = Trim(.Cells(ROW_HEADER, c)) ' header text
            If dictCol.exists(k) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate header '" & k & "' at column " & c, vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf Len(k) > 0 Then
                dictCol(k) = c ' column number
            End If
        Next
    End With

    For r = 1 To UBound(arID): arID(r, 1) = Trim(arID(r, 1)): Next
    MsgBox dictCol.Count & " columns found on sheet " & ws2.Name, vbInformation
    
    ' update sheet1
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws1
        lastcol = .Cells(ROW_HEADER, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            id = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            
            ' locate row on sheet2
            m = Application.Match(id, arID, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                ' scan columns
                For c = 2 To lastcol
                    k = trim(.Cells(ROW_HEADER, c))
                    ' find col on sheet2
                    If dictCol.exists(k) Then
                        ' update if different
                        If .Cells(r, c) <> ws2.Cells(m, dictCol(k)) Then
                            .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' mark yellow for checking
                            .Cells(r, c) = ws2.Cells(m, dictCol(k))
                            n = n + 1
                         End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Column " & k & " not found", vbCritical
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                Debug.Print id, m
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' end
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows scanned " & vbLf & _
           n & " cells updated", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: lovely, I will try your code in about 2 hours and if works I will let you know and tag this as a solved :) appreciate all your help.

Comment: can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have used your code in module, when I start it, I receive a message "24 columns found on sheet2 (amount of columns in sheet2), I can only click "ok", once I do it, 2nd pop-up says "509 rows scanned, 0 cells updated" (509 rows on sheet1).

I believe the code works well, but it doesn't replace data in cells in sheet1.

Comment: 1st row is used for headers (A1 = employee ID, B1= Resource name) etc.
Column A all the way down is with employees ID (both sheets).

Comment: Checked, there are no extra spaces in any of the column headers (apart from normal spaces between words) and no spaces at all in column A where I have employee IDs

Comment: @Marcin What was shown in the Immediate window on the VB Editor, are there a list of IDs with Error 2042

Comment: Yes, every single of them has an error 2042.

Comment: @marcin OK try update code. I think the problem was your ID's are numbers so arID was the wrong vartype to match.

Comment: now it's runing to an error. First pop-up is x columns found on sheet sheet2, I press ok, then "Column Subgrade 2020 not found".

Comment: @marcin is that a column on sheet 1 that is not on sheet 2 ? if it is comment out the 2 lines `MsgBox "Column " & k & " not found", vbCritical` and `Exit Sub`

Comment: It worked, all date replaced and makred with yellow! 

Great support, thank you very much - if there is any way to reward you I am more than happy to do it :)